# Why is the "else" branch executed along with one of the "if" branches?

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a problem and know wat do do with this. Here's the piece of code of a function.

```
if(rClass.equals("SavingsAccount")) {
    account = new SavingsAccount(rId,rName,start, end);
}
if(rClass.equals("DraftAccount")) {
    account = new DraftAccount(rId,rName,start, end);
}
if(rClass.equals("VIPAccount")) {
    account = new VIPAccount(rId,rName,start, end);
}
else {
    account = null;
}
```

The variable `String rClass` is read from a file and it is 100% "SavingsAccount" but it jumps all the lines and at the end i have `account = null`, why??
Even tried to put this after the if's:

```
String rClass = "SavingsAccount";
```

The result is the same.

Comment: Consider editing your title to more accurately reflect the problem you're having. Thanks @dasblinkenlight.

Comment: Are you sure because `SavingsAccount ` can look like `SavingAccount` which can look like `SavıngsAccount` There are many variations which look similar but are not the same.  I suggest you print the `.hashCode()` of the two strings before the `if` statement`

Comment: Don't know if this is what you already do, but have a look at the factory pattern.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that you have used 2 if statements and an if-else

```
//first if statement
if(rClass.equals("SavingsAccount")) {
    account = new SavingsAccount(rId,rName,start, end);
}

//second if statement
if(rClass.equals("DraftAccount")) {
    account = new DraftAccount(rId,rName,start, end);
}

//And an if-else
if(rClass.equals("VIPAccount")) {
    account = new VIPAccount(rId,rName,start, end);
}
else {
    account = null;
}
```

So you set account to `account = new SavingsAccount(rId,rName,start, end);` then later set it to null.

You want an else-if

```
if(rClass.equals("SavingsAccount")) {
    account = new SavingsAccount(rId,rName,start, end);
}else if(rClass.equals("DraftAccount")) {
    account = new DraftAccount(rId,rName,start, end);
}else if(rClass.equals("VIPAccount")) {
    account = new VIPAccount(rId,rName,start, end);
}else {
    account = null;
}
```

Comment: You are a fast typer, Rich, my short version of this answer took longer than this full version

Comment: @MarshallTigerus Stack overflow trains us to be fast! I quite like the way you express it in yours as well though so +1

Answer (score 3):

Do it that way:

```
if(rClass.equals("SavingsAccount")) {
    account = new SavingsAccount(rId,rName,start, end);
}
else if(rClass.equals("DraftAccount")) {
    account = new DraftAccount(rId,rName,start, end);
}
else if(rClass.equals("VIPAccount")) {
    account = new VIPAccount(rId,rName,start, end);
}
else {
    account = null;
}
```

Or better use *switch statement*:

```
switch(rClass) {
  case "SavingsAccount":
    account = new SavingsAccount(rId, rName, start, end);
    break;
  case "DraftAccount":
    account = new DraftAccount(rId, rName, start, end);
    break;
  case "VIPAccount":
    account = new VIPAccount(rId, rName, start, end);
    break;
  default:
    account = null;
}
```

Comment: You should add that your second solution works only in Java>=1.7

Comment: @JakubHr and, in particular, you can't use it on Android.

Comment: You could use a switch statement, if you create, say, an `AccountType` enum, convert the string with `valueOf`, and then switch on the enum. Works on Java 1.5 or later, and on Android.

Answer (score 3):

You have a logic problem.

Basically you are saying:

If this is a savings account do this

If this is a draft account do this

If this is a VIP account do this, or if it isn't a VIP account, set it to NULL

You need to change the second and third if statements to else if statements

Answer (score 3):

You have to change your code like that:

```
if(rClass.equals("SavingsAccount")) {
    account = new SavingsAccount(rId,rName,start, end);
}
else if(rClass.equals("DraftAccount")) {
    account = new DraftAccount(rId,rName,start, end);
}
else if(rClass.equals("VIPAccount")) {
    account = new VIPAccount(rId,rName,start, end);
}
else {
    account = null;
}
```

Because in your case you first assiging new SavingsAccount correctly, but then else block is reached anyway and it nulls out your reference.